# Julia generics function type parameter

Tags: generics, types, julia

I defined a function as follows:

```
function approx_pi(n)
    tot = Float64(0.0)
    for i in 1:n
        x = rand()
        y = rand()
        if x^2 + y^2 < 1
            tot+=1
        end
    end
    tot / n * 4
end

println(approx_pi(100_000_000))
```

I would like to use the same function but return a Float128 instead:

```
using Quadmath

function approx_pi(n)
    tot = Float128(0.0)
    for i in 1:n
        x = rand()
        y = rand()
        if x^2 + y^2 < 1
            tot+=1
        end
    end
    tot / n * 4
end

println(approx_pi(100_000_000))
```

I assume there is a way to achieve that through the equivalent of C# or Java generics:

```
function approx_pi{T}(n)
    ...
end

println(approx_pi{Float128}(100_000_000))
```

I could not figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? `tot` should be an integer, normally an `Int64`. Why do you want it to be a float? `tot` will always be less than `n`, which is an `Int64`, too. There's no purpose in making them floats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was said, you can abuse Julia type system, but this is highly non-idiomatic and should never ever be used in practice.

```
struct ApproxPi{T} end

function ApproxPi{T}(n) where T
    tot = zero(T) 
    for i in 1:n
        x = rand(T)
        y = rand(T)
        if x^2 + y^2 < 1
            tot+=1
        end
    end
    tot / n * 4
end

julia> ApproxPi{Float32}(100_000)
3.14144f0
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I want to follow the best practices. That said, I would appreciate if you could mention the use case of parametric types. I also do not understand why a struct had to be defined, then a function with the same name. I kind of guess that this is a "constructor" for the struct? If so, indeed it's a misuse of the type system. Finally, what is the best source to read about idiomatic Julia constructs.

Comment: The best source of Julia type system is the manual. In particular, the parametric type system is described here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Types

Regarding your question, you can not define arbitrary parametric function (i.e. function with curly brackets), only parametric constructor. So, yes, I defined type and constructor, which instead of actually creating variable of the required type, just output some float.

Answer (score 6):

Types are first-class citizens in Julia, so that you can use them as function arguments in the same way you would use any other value.

For example in this case, you could simply specify the desired type as an additional argument:

```julia
julia> function approx_pi(T, n)
           tot = zero(T)   # Better than T(0)
           for i in 1:n
               x = rand(T) # Not sure whether you want these to be of
               y = rand(T) # type T, or remain as Float64
               if x^2 + y^2 < 1
                   tot+=1
               end
           end
           tot / n * 4
       end
approx_pi (generic function with 1 method)

julia> approx_pi(BigFloat, 1_000_000)
3.141276000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to use a syntax such as `approx_pi{Float64}(n)`?

Comment: Such a syntax would look more like the instantiation of a parametric type. You could (ab)use this observation to get what you want, but this would probably not be considered idiomatic in Julia. Is there a reason why you'd like to use this specific syntax?

Comment: Well, I see this technique used when creating a new array: example: Array{Int64}(undef, 10). In this case, the type is not passed as an argument. You might refer me to best practices docs on when to use each technique, otherwise why would parametric types exist?

Comment: `Array{Int}(undef, 10)` is exactly what it is: the creation of a new object. This is different from calculating some arbitrary function.

Comment: @FrançoisFévotte Thanks again for your response. I have upvoted your answer, which has been appreciated by others.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a third variant, a derivative of Andrej's answer, which is, I believe, more idiomatic.  Namely, instead of "abusing" the constructor function to do calculations, we just construct a polymorphic closure by an explicit type:

```
struct ApproxPi{T} end

function (::ApproxPi{T})(n) where T
    tot = zero(T) 
    for i in 1:n
        x = rand(T)
        y = rand(T)
        if x^2 + y^2 < 1
            tot += 1
        end
    end
    tot / n * 4
end

const approx_pi = ApproxPi{Float32}()

julia> approx_pi(100_000)
3.14144f0
```

Which should be still practical if you are not changing the types dynamically all the time.